# How to specify a font from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, fonts, mobile-safari

I am trying to customize a view-src bookmarklet for iPad. [This one](http://www.frankfiedler.de/2010/12/iphone-show-source/) is looking pretty good so far.

But I want to make it just a little more readable: The Courier (New) font is a bit ugly even (especially?) on the retina display and I'd prefer any one of DejaVu Sans Mono, Monaco, Lucida Console, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono.

I tried to modify the bookmarklet script by adding:

```
pre.style.fontFamily = '"DejaVu Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Monaco;';
```

It's not doing the trick.

Perhaps prettyprint cancels out my fontFamily setting when it loads. Maybe I can set it at the end of the script somehow...

Comment: I'm not sure, but does iPad have any of this fonts?

Comment: That's right. Turns out none of these great fonts are included, I saw them in some apps I have (like Textastic) but they're not available to   MobileSafari. I chose to simply set the Courier to bold so at least it's easier to see the colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because Lucida Console, dejaVu sans mono and Monaco are no avaiible natively on the ipad. Unless you have added them as [Webfont](http://iosfonts.com/), this will have absolutely no effect on a IOS device. here is a list of the ipad native fonts: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Crap. Which ones of these are monospace?

Comment: `pre.style.fontFamily = 'mono';` should achieve that.

Comment: @meo I'd love to do a css solution but I don't think that's possible since i'm dealing with a bookmarklet here. i.e. to be able to use this bit of code to view the src on any website I want. So it's all client-side js.

Comment: @Steven Lu. ok then go with "Andale Mono" or Courier

Comment: Quite strange. I'm on 5.1 (new iPad) and opening the daringfireball.net link in my ipad shows it using Times to draw Andale Mono. Monaco appears to not be Times but it definitely isn't Monaco either.

Comment: @StevenLu sorry i have no iPad i cant check... what about courier ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to change it *from* Courier though.

Comment: sorry im afraid its the only monospace font on IOS :(

Comment: What about @font-face? Maybe i'll post another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9558/discussion-between-meo-and-steven-lu)

Comment: I think I'm gonna end up just using either Courier (bold) or Futura.

Comment: Yep. I'm going with font-weight = bold, Courier New, color = white, background-color = some kind of dark grey. Very readable website src with syntax highlighting via bookmarklet. =) All's left now is some js code for auto-formatting...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only monospace font available on iOS is Courier (and Courier New, I believe). You'll have to go with:
`pre.style.fontFamily = '"Courier New", Courier, mono';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
element.style.fontFamily = "Fontname1,alternative1,alternative2";
```

About the iPad problem, have you tried Google fonts?

http://www.google.com/webfonts

From their site:

---

**What browsers are supported?**

The Google Web Fonts API is compatible with the following browsers:

Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+

Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+

Apple Safari: version 3.1+

Opera: version 10.5+

Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+

**Does the Google Web Fonts API work on mobile devices?**

The Google Web Fonts API works reliably on the vast majority of modern mobile operating systems, including Android 2.2+ and iOS 4.2+ (iPhone, iPad, iPod). Support for earlier iOS versions is limited.

---

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Well, google fonts does not have the fonts I like, but this got me searching and maybe I could use @font-face somehow. Or SVG fonts.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Well @ font-face is great if your project is targeted for css3 browsers only. So if you plan to expand to ie6+ and other browsers older versions its going to be harder, otherwise @ font-face is great. You might also want to read this article (not my blog , just ran into it) on svg fonts. http://jeremie.patonnier.net/post/2011/02/07/Why-are-SVG-Fonts-so-different

Comment: Oh sorry about that, i looked into the w3.org site, they mention it under css3 http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-webfonts-20020802/#font-descriptions

Even w3schools.com does http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

I think i came across a css2 article on font-face but i guess it was deprecated in css2 and reintroduced in css3. I'm not too sure what the real situation is,but this would be a good thing to know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version I am using now, it's Frank Fiedler's bookmarklet, slightly modified to set the `<pre>` to bold and using the "sunburst" prettify CSS rather than the default one.

```
javascript:(function(){
  var w = window.open('about:blank'),
  doc = w.document;
  doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Source of ' + location.href +
    '</title><meta name=\'viewport\' content=\'width=device-width\' />' +
    '<link rel=\'stylesheet\''+
    ' href=\'http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/sunburst.css\''+
    ' type=\'text/css\'/>' +
    '</head><body></body></html>');
  doc.close();
  var pre = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement('pre'));
  pre.style.overflow = 'auto';
  pre.style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
  pre.style.border = 'none';
  pre.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  pre.className = 'prettyprint';
  pre.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(document.documentElement.innerHTML));
  var lib = doc.createElement('script');
  lib.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  lib.setAttribute('src','http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js');
  doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(lib);
  var call = doc.createElement('script');
  call.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  var txt = doc.createTextNode('window.setTimeout(function () {prettyPrint();},800);');
  call.appendChild(txt);
  doc.body.appendChild(call);  
}());
```

looks pretty pro:

[image]